# Append a sequence of numbers after each word in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a function that needs to append a sequence of numbers (starting with 1) at the end of each word in the string. Here is my function:

```
function insertNum(str) {
    var word = new Array();
    word = str.split(" ");
    return src[0] + "1 " + src[1] + "2 " + src[2] + "3 " + src[3];
}

insertNum("word word word word."); // return "word1 word2 word3 word4."
insertNum("word word word."); // return "word1 word2 word3."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it...

```
function insertNum(str) {
    var index = 1;
    return str.replace(/\w\b/g, function(match) {
        return match + index++;
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3tkt/).

Comment: Good use of a lambda function.

Comment: What about the last 'word.' here? Wouldn't that become word.[somedigit]?

Comment: @KooiInc Nup, check the fiddle.

Comment: @alex, yup, missed the `\b` part.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way:

```
function insertNum(str) {
    var word = new Array();
    word = str.split(" ");
    var tmp = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= word.length; i ++) {
       tmp += word[i-1] + i + " ";
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count = 1;
    String s = "This is nice";

    String a[] = s.split(" ");

    for(String m : a){
        System.out.print(m + count++ + " ");
    }
```